# Check for installed packages that aren't in package.json

Tags: node.js, module, package

Is there a way to see what packages are installed in `node_modules` that aren't in `package.json`? I know that [npm-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check) and [dependency-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dependency-check) can be used to check modules currently in `package.json`, but I wonder if there is a way to look for packages that might just be extraneously installed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `npm list` or its shortcut `npm ls` to [list installed packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls).

Packages that not in the `package.json` will be marked as **extraneous**.

There is also `npm ll` or `npm la` which lists extended information about packages.

Comment: This didn't work for me; it output a massive dep tree, but none of the extra packages I had in node_modules were marked as extraneous that I could tell. I ran `npm list | grep extraneous` to look for them, as the tree was too big to manually traverse easily.

Comment: It's strange. Are you sure you have modules that's not in the `package.json`? Try to use `npm list --depth 0` to print only top level of the tree.

Comment: Ahhh it was in dev dependencies and I didn't notice it. My bad. All good. You're right, this works, just tested. Thanks!

Comment: this didn't work for me, i tried doing --depth 0 and i couldn't find any packages listed as extraneous.